# How long will live lobsters last in the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, storage-lifetime, lobster

My parents just got back from Boston. Since we were looking after their dog, they bought us 2 live lobsters as a "thank you". We've named them Pinchy and James. They were bought Saturday afternoon and flew home in styrofoam with ice and wet newspaper over them. The guy that sold them to my parents said they would last till Monday night if they were kept in the fridge and covered with wet newspaper. Is that right? When should we cook them? We have dinner plans already for Sunday night. What can we do to make sure they stay alive / fresh?

Comment: +1 for the title alone. I wanted to say something witty in response but I'm simply dumbfounded by the extreme awesomeness of this visual.

Comment: @JN Web, Pinchy died inadvertently in the bath tub. James was named after my brother.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They should be fine until Monday.  Do just as he said...keep them in the fridge covered with damp newspaper.  Cook them tomorrow or Monday.

If you can't/don't for some reason have time to cook them then just stick them in the freezer alive.  They'll freeze and you can then cook them another time in the future.

Comment: They lived to tell the tail, as it were. Thanks.